# get div to cover whole page even after scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I have a div called 'alert' which is used in the same way as as the javascript `alert()` function. It covers the whole page until you scroll down, then the part of the page which was not previously visible is not covered. Is there a way to cover the whole page and not just the visible viewport? NB. I don't want to use `position:fixed`. this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x0o36bh0/) demonstrates what I mean. Thank you.

```
#alert{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    background-color:rgba(187,201,247,0.5);
    z-index:3;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: Add to the parent `position:relative` - `body{position:relative}`

Answer (score 5):

***CSS***

```
html,body{
    position:relative;
}

#text{
    height:1000px;
}
#alert{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    background-color:rgba(187,201,247,0.5);
    z-index:3;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x0o36bh0/3/)